Why does RXJS Observable stops emitting after getting error
I am trying to access datas every time the user changes the input value.
The search can return an error.
In this case, I want to disable the use of AI (semanticDisabled) for future searchs and then reload a search.
Every time the user changes the search, it activates this callback :
  stackSearch(hybridSearch: boolean) {
    this.search$.next({
      search: this.search,
      fulltext: true,
      semantic: hybridSearch,
    });
  }

search$ is defined like that : private search$ = new Subject<TSearch>();
When the observable gets a new value, a new search is made. semanticDisabled is applyed to the search with a map() and then the service search is made.
this.batcher = this.search$
  .pipe(
    map((search) => ({
      ...search,
      semantic: !this.semanticDisabled && search.semantic,    // Disable semantic
    })),
    switchMap((search) =>
      this.service.search({
        ...search!,
        ...this.searchConfig,
      })
    ),
    catchError((error) => {
      if (error.message === 'semantic_unavailable') {
        this.semanticDisabled = true;
        this.stackSearch(false); // Reload without semantic
      } else {
        this.requestError = true;
        this.res = undefined;
      }
      return EMPTY;
    })
  )

My problem is that when I have an error, $search stops emitting values.
But I'd like the program to re-execute the search without AI.
I tried to use retry() and retryWhen() but it doesn't works.
Retry doesn't allow to change disabledSemantic to true and RetryWhen repeats the code. I could probably use them differently.
Could you help me please ?

Move the catchError inside the switchMap so that the root stream is not destroyed by the error/complete only the stream upto the switchMap, stops, and future values will be processed by the switchMap.
this.batcher = this.search$
  .pipe(
    map((search) => ({
      ...search,
      semantic: !this.semanticDisabled && search.semantic,    // Disable semantic
    })),
    switchMap((search) =>
      this.service.search({
        ...search!,
        ...this.searchConfig,
      }).pipe(
          catchError((error) => {
              if (error.message === 'semantic_unavailable') {
                this.semanticDisabled = true;
                this.stackSearch(false); // Reload without semantic
             } else {
                this.requestError = true;
                this.res = undefined;
             }
             return EMPTY;
           })
        )
    ),
    
  )


Thanks for the answer.
When I copied the code, I got the error : Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'Promise'. Should I implement my service search function differently ?
Here is the end of its definition :
const req = this.http.get(path, { headers, params });
try {
return (await firstValueFrom(req)) as any;
}
catch (e: any) {
throw e instanceof HttpErrorResponse && e.status === 429
? new Error('semantic_unavailable')
: e;
}
I tried to just return the observable. The pipe then works but it breaks all the other code

@NicolasDelahaie try without the firstValue from instead return this.http.get(path, { headers, params }); then for the error handling you need to use catch error from rxjs instead of try catch

I tried implementing await firstValueFrom after subscribe, enclosed in a try-catch block, but faced an issue where switchMap became ineffective. When calling a slow API followed by a fast one, the latter doesn't cancel the former. Also, the error handling in subscribe isn't triggered at all. It seems that returning an Observable directly from my search function may not be ideal. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

@NicolasDelahaie actually Its difficult to debug the scenario without the full details, could you share a stackblitz highlighting the issue for me to check it, with the entire code details its difficult to understand "When calling a slow API followed by a fast one, the latter doesn't cancel the former. Also, the error handling in subscribe isn't triggered at all."

This is my first StackBlitz project, and I've attempted to remove any superfluous code for clarity. Please let me know if anything is unclear. I encountered issues with the visual input component; however, it wouldn't have been functional for this demonstration as the search API is not public. here

Is there someone ?

@NicolasDelahaie try this stackblitz sorry missed to check this!
